# uitableviewcell background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UItableView (grouped style). I wanted to customize it so that it appears like a "Stick it" or a "Post it" with a yellow background interface.

Hence is added the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIView *backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

This actually worked. I was able to achieve the yellow background, but the separator line is missing. Can some1 help me out ?

Is this the best way to do it? Or should i create an image for the cell and use it as the backgroundView?

Comment: separator line between cell Or within cell ..

Comment: @Jhaliya : between cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Outdated.*

Why are you creating a custom background view? If you only want to achieve a yellow color you can customize your color by using `UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:` to create your own color and just add it to `cell setBackgroundColor:UIColor`. It seems like the seperator is being completely overwritten if you add a background view in grouped table view. If you still want to have a custom UIView as your background, I suggest adding a custom tableViewCell that looks like your seperator. You can regulate this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Working code for my first suggestion:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Comment: thanks. But when i used, i don see any change in the background color

Comment: so if you basically only have setBackgroundColor and no custom backgroundview, you still don't get a background change? because there shouldn't be anything overwriting this. do you mind uploading your class on pastebin or something?

Comment: Actually i do have added a background to the view.

Comment: Great that you figured it out :)

Comment: your suggestion is not compatible with earlier version of iphone, which was viable when I wrote this answer - however, the version you are describing is indeed more correct

Comment: Actually, as pkclSoft specifies, this is a change that was added after the answer was submitted.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, none of the above answers are (I believe) correct.  According to the doco:

> **Note**: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the delegate and not in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

So rather than call `setBackgroundColor` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you should be doing so in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ShoppingList *object = (ShoppingList*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([object isComplete] == YES) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    } else {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
}
```

This I've found works perfectly, and fits in with the way the rest of the table cell rendering works.  There's no need for any background views to be added or anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised that worked to set the background color. The proper method to setting a UITableViewCell background is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Also, I notice you don't have any reuse code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I'm hoping you just didn't paste this in, but that's kind of a big no-no. [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: This is just a duplicate of my answer, but it's the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you to put inside "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

```
....................

if (cell == nil) {

....................

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

....................

    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Comment: did you drop the previous one with "UIView *backgroundView" ?

Comment: yes i did. But actually i want the cells alone to be yellow in color. I have a different backgroundimage for the tableview

Answer (score 0):

Set the [separatorStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the tableview to [UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle).

Should be something like below.

```
myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Comment: I tried it. I guess the backgroundView is covering the separator line as well

Comment: @Narayanan : How are you deciding the height of each cell ?

Comment: I am sry...why do we need the height of the cell /?

Comment: @Narayanan : If your cell content vary from one cell to others. you need to calculate the height for cell in - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: @Narayanan : If it is constant across all cell then set a value to rowHeight property of UITableView. like below myTableView.rowHeight = 45.0f;

Comment: see so post for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693589/setting-variable-uitableviewcell-height

Comment: I think i am doing something basically wrong. Is it a good option to create an image to the height and width of the cell and use it as a backgroundView?

Comment: @Narayanan : I am not sure dude, but you could try with some other images,Which have little short height then you are using.